# shape-outside not responding to alpha channel

Tags: html, wordpress, css, alpha, css-shapes

I'm experimenting with [CSS Shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside). I can't seem to get the image shape to work. As far as I can tell, my image has an alpha channel, it's just that the browser is not reading it.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.kfcartography.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/weirdshape2.png">
  <p>Text that should be flowing around the weird shape.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  max-width: 300px;
  color: black;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: url("http://www.kfcartography.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/weirdshape2.png");
  shape-image-threshold: 0.1;
  shape-margin: 10px;
}
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/kingfisher13/pen/vOyKWE?editors=110).

The original shape was created in Illustrator and saved as a PNG-24 with transparency (which should add an Alpha channel). I've also opened it in GIMP and played around there with masks and adding an alpha channel (though it already had one from the Illustrator file).

What am I missing?

Comment: In the codepen, there is a CORS issue ...  I think that a cross origin is ok for the image, but not for the shape

Comment: That's the issue. Didn't even think to look at the console since JS wasn't involved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encode you image to base64 you don't get the CROS issue.

The issue you get thou is that it clog's up your CSS file a lot...

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
}
img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
  shape-image-threshold: 0.7;
  shape-margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.kfcartography.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/weirdshape2.png" /><span>Text that should be flowing around the weird shape.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure encoding an image into the css is workable as a large-scale solution (I guess its fine for experiments though).

Comment: if its not an  experiment you shouldn't have the cross browser domain issue.